# How can python read filename with special characters

Tags: python-3.x

I want to open file name which conatins special characters but python is giving os error.

I have tried opening the file with `unicode` but it didn't worked either

```
title = "djhf???jdf.html"
title1 = u'{}'.format(title)
with open(title, 'w') as f:
    f.write("Heyya")
```

It should open file which has special characters in its name.

Comment: What `special characters` are present in the file name, I used the file name `djhf???jdf.html` and was able to write to the file! This was in Mac OSX though

Comment: Note that, in Windows, `?` is not allowed in filenames.

Comment: Is there any way that special characters such as `?` Can be allowed as a filename in  Windows os